# qr decomposition of a matrix

Tags: tensorflow.js

I want to compute the qr decomposition of a matrix
Here is my code

```
const a = tf.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2]);
a.print()
const [b, c] = tf.qr(a)
b.print()
```

But it is throwing the following error

> tf.qr is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is not clear about [tf.qr](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.5/#qr) and [tf.gramSchmidt](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.5/#gramSchmidt). You need to use `tf.linalg.qr` and `tf.linalg.gramSchmidt` instead as you can see in the unit test code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-core/blob/v0.12.11/src/ops/linalg_ops_test.ts#L100)

```
const [b, c] = tf.linalg.qr(a)
```

```js
const a = tf.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2]);
a.print()
const [b, c] = tf.linalg.qr(a)
b.print()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tensorflow/0.12.4/tf.js"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```